# How to check if an item in a dictionary exists in CSV file?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a dictionary and a CSV file (which is actually tab delimited):

`dict1`:

```
{1 : ['Charles', 22],
2: ['James', 36],
3: ['John', 18]}
```

`data.csv`:

```
[ 22 | Charles goes to the cinema | Activity    ]
[ 46 | John is a butcher          | Profession  ]
[ 95 | Charles is a firefighter   | Profession  ]
[ 67 | James goes to the zoo      | Activity    ]
```

I want to take the string (name) in the first item of `dict1`'s value and search for it in the second column of the csv. If the name appears in the sentence, I want to print the first (and only the first) sentence.

But I am having problem with the searching - how do I access the column/row data while iterating through `dict1`? I have tried something like this:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    for (id, (name, age)) in dict1.items():
        if name in reader.row[1] # reader.row[1] is wrong!!!
        print(reader.row[1])
```

Comment: You don't iterate through a dictionary here, that's the point of the O(1) lookup speed

Comment: How large is your csv?

Comment: @roganjosh you iterate through a dictionary if you want to use each key in a dictionary...

Comment: The approach is backwards. You want to be iterating through the rows and checking to see if the entries are in the dict, not iterating the dict and seeing if it matches each row

Comment: ", I want to print the first (and only the first) sentence"....... by "sentence" do you mean "column"?  If not, then please clarify what you mean here.

Comment: @roganjosh Depends on how large the csv is, the liklihood of a name being in a sentence, etc etc.  We need more info to decide which way to iterate.

Comment: I take it back.  What matters is whether the csv and dict are *static*.  How often will you be iterating over his csv?

Comment: Hi both, the dictionary has around 5,000 lines and the cab around 20,000.

Comment: I am suspecting that @roganjosh is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *roganjosh* is right. Better way is traverse CSV file and find any key.

```py
requested = {d[0] for d in dict1.values()}
with open('/tmp/f.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        sentence = row[1]
        found = {n for n in requested if n in sentence}
        for n in found:
            print(f'{n}: {sentence}')
        requested -= found
        if not requested:  # optimization, all names used
            break
```

---

EDIT: answer for question, not for my imagination

---

EDIT2: after clarification (and some new requirements)... I hope I hit.

Prints sentence only ones per row. It not check if the same sentence is in another row. You can use `set()` for keep matched sentences and print them when CVS file has been proceed.

I used regex for match worlds not any sub-string.

```py
import csv
import re

requested = {re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(d[0]) + r'\b') for d in dict1.values()}
with open('/tmp/f.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        sentence = row[1]
        found = {n for n in requested if n.search(sentence)}
        if found:
            requested -= found
            print(sentence)
        if not requested:
            break
```

---

EDIT3: restore hit names (new requirement – like in real dev project :-P)

First, you can match more than one name (see `len(found)`).

In last example you can recover name from compiled regex (because before `r'\b`' was added before and after name):

```py
found_names = [r.pattern[2:-2] for r in found]
```

But I don't think it's best way.

Better way is add original name to `requested`. I deiced to use `set` of `tuples`. Operations on sets are very fast.

```py
requested = {(re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(d[0]) + r'\b'), d[0])
             for d in dict1.values()}
with open('/tmp/f.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t'):
        sentence = row[1]
        found = {(r, n) for r, n in requested if r.search(sentence)}
        if found:
            found_names = tuple(n for r, n in found)
            print(found_names, sentence)
            requested -= found
        if not requested:
            break
```

Now found names (original `d[0]`) are in list `found_names`. You can user it as you want. For example change to string (do replace `found_name=` and print` lines):

```py
found_names = ', '.join(n for r, n in found)
print(f'{found_names}: {sentence}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm afraid I can't get this to work! For me, that just prints the very first `row[1]`/`sentence` in `csvfile`, and (when I ask it to print `d[0]` for debugging) a `d[0]` that does not appear in that `row[1]`.  If my question wasn't clear, I would like one `row[1]` to be printed for each `d[0]` in `dict1.values()`, and for that `row[1]` to be the first `row[1]` in the `csvfile` that contains that `d[0]`.

Comment: It's strange, it works for me or I don't understand the clue. If it prints very first row maybe the first line (row[1] contains one of the substting defined in dict1? Could check it? The best would be to see all input data if it possible. Ohhh... for each `d[0]` not for any! Sorry, I'm changing my answer now...

Comment: Yes! Although upon testing I realised this is picks up the `d[0]` string in other words (eg 'Jon' in 'Jonathan') - ie `d[0]` needs to be surrounded by spaces. I could add a space around `d[0]` when I am assembling `dict1`, but this is messy. Is there a way to add spaces when doing the iteration?

Comment: Also I recognise this wasn't clear in my original question, because I hadn't thought about it then, but this will result in a `sentence` being assigned and printed more than once if there is more than one `d[0]` in that `sentence`. What would be the easiest way to stop this? I guess instead of just doing a `print`, `n` and `sentence` could be stored in a dictionary which could be checked for the `sentence` during the iteration?

Comment: Yeah, I specially added printing sentence for any author. Now I print once per row. If sentence can be repeated in another row, use `set()`. Regex detect only whole-words now.

Comment: Yay, thanks so much, I think we're there! One final bit: how would I access the dictionary values in the iteration? For example, if I didn't just want to print sentence, but also `d[0]` and the key?

Comment: In first example it was easy in second not. I'll add it to answer.